# Define class constraint on interface or variable

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I have a situation where I need to require that a variable is of a certain type, but that it *also* implements a specific custom interface. Specifically, I want to require that the object be a `FrameworkElement`, but that it also implement a custom interface, call it `IExample`.

Is there any way I can do this from either the declaration of `IExample` or the actual variable? I'm envisioning something like this (pseudo syntax):

```
public FrameworkElement<IExample> ChildView { get; set; }
```

Either that or I want to declare it as a constraint on the interface itself:

```
public interface IExample : FrameworkElement
```

Are either of these possible in C#? Are there alternatives that can accomplish the same thing? Basically I just want to require that instances be of a subclass of `FrameworkElement` that also implements `IExample`.

Comment: It is not possible to do exactly what you want, as far as I know. As a workaround you might declare property of type FrameworkElement in IExample interface. All implementations of IExample will then just do "return this" for this property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a generics constraint at the class level and then apply it to the property as properties themselves cannot directly define constraints.

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T : FrameworkElement, IExample {
  public T ChildView { get; set; }
}
```

Or on an interface

```
public interface ISomeInterface<T> where T : FrameworkElement, IExample {
  T ChildView { get; set; }
}
```

---

Or at the method level if you want to take a type in as a parameter that conforms to both being of type `FrameworkElement` and also implementing `IExample`

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(T someParameter) where T : FrameworkElement, IExample 
{ /*do something with instance someParameter*/)
```

Comment: Ok this would work fine for declaring the subclasses, but how would I refer to a variable in a general way that could support multiple/arbitrary implementations? I don't want to require the variable be a `SomeClass`.

Comment: @devios1 - you can just a easily turn `SomeClass` into an interface and apply that interface to a subtype. But if that is not what you mean maybe you can elaborate on what you mean by referring to a variable in a general way? Maybe add an example to your question and why this would not work or how you see it being more loosely coupled?

Comment: @devios1 - If you mean you have methods that take these instances then you can make those methods generic as well without requiring the type to be generic.

Comment: Ok so if I declare the interface itself to be generic, would I be able to create my variable as `IExample<FrameworkElement>` and have it work with subclasses of `FrameworkElement` too (so long as they implement `IExample`)?

Comment: @devios1 - I updated my answer, maybe that is more specific to what you are talking about? At some point you need to consumer your expected type, it is at these points where you want to make the incoming parameter or type adhere to a generic constraint(s).

Comment: Ok this might actually work. Your hint of declaring the interface itself as generic got me on the right track. Now I'm just referring to all of my variables as type `IExample<FrameworkElement>` and also implementing the subclasses as `IExample<FrameworkElement>` which so far seems to work.

Comment: @devios1 - `IExample<FrameworkElement>` seems like an interface where members have a generic constraint of `FrameworkElement` though. Ill update again with how it would work with the generic constraint on an interface.

Comment: What if I want SomeMethod to _return_ T? But of course I dont want to specify exact type when calling that method. I think thats what OP wants.

Comment: @Evk - I missed that. I do not think that is possible then using generics. The best alternative is to use interfaces or a base class that implements both interface and the root class.